# Is $P(X/c < Y)$ equivalent to $P(X < cy)$?

Tags: probability

Say I have this: $P(\frac{X}{5} < y)$

Is this equivalent to: $P(X < 5y)$?

Why?

Comment: Because $\frac X 5 <y$ iff $X <5y$.

Comment: The statement in title is true only if $c>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's indeed equal because $$\{\omega \mid \frac{X(\omega )}{5} < y\}=\{\omega \mid X(\omega )<5y\}.$$